# Windows PATH variable not working for Composer

Tags: php, windows, environment-variables, composer-php

I've installed Composer on Windows 10 using installer, but it doesn't seem to work properly. When I try running `composer` in the console, it throws an error:

```
'""' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I rebooted my pc twice, run the console as an administrator and checked the PATH variable. It contained the Composer install path (`C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin`), but for some reason it doesn't work. I tried running the composer directly after cd to this folder, and it worked, but it doesn't work otherwise.

'where composer' prints out the following:

```
C:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP_7.4\composer.bat
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.bat
```

The first path refers to the folder where the PHP is installed, the second is the executable itself

If I try to run 'C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer', it works as intended, so the Composer itself is installed correctly

How do I get the PATH variable for Composer work properly?

Comment: Perhaps you have a `composer` executable somewhere else in your PATH. What do you get if you run `where composer` from a command prompt?

Comment: Where is that file and what is its precise name? In MS Windows, the extension is often significant to how a file "works". Also, point is, if it is ".php", you need to inform the OS that those files should be executed with PHP and where that executable is. BTW: Make sure you can actually run it with its full path and/or by passing it as argument to the interpreter. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: The file is called just `composer`, it doesn't require php to run it, since the command works just fine when I am at C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin. So, the full name is: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer (no file extension, I checked)

Comment: `where composer` returns the following:
C:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP_7.4\composer.bat
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.bat

One of those is the path to the executable, so I think it should work fine, but it doesn't

Comment: `'""' is not recognized...` is a very unusual error message. Did you just type `composer` in cmd.exe?

Comment: Yes, I typed just `composer`. But the same error goes with any parameters that I try to pass to it. It works only with the full path

Comment: Two things wrong here: 1) Windows script is not `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer`, it's `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.bat` 2) You are running `C:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP_7.4\composer.bat`—whatever that is, it isn't the Composer you just installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the `C:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP_7.4\composer.bat` file, and it worked fine.

This folder is the PHP installation folder, which came packed with a local server that I installed previously. For some reason, it had a broken `composer.bat`, and when I was installing Composer, I checked "Add PHP folder to the PATH variable". That is why when I tried to run `composer`, it ran the broken file and was throwing a weird error.

Thank you, Álvaro González, for helping me to figure that out!